# URL link in php

Tags: php

```
 echo '<td><a href="'.$row_sv['website'].'" target="_self\">'.$row_sv['name'].'</a></td>';
```

I don't want to use any target and changed it like this but it messed up my table

```
 echo '<td><a href="'.$row_sv['website].'$row_sv['name'].'</a></td>';
```

something wrong?

Comment: you didn't close the tags... please, some basic debugging. Take a look at the source of your page

Comment: All you need is a rubber ducky.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: Also, please make sure that you're properly escaping `$row_sv['website']` and `$row_sv['name']` for HTML attribute and HTML contexts, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make such pieces clearer I prefer using templates. In your case that would be:

```
 printf( '<td><a href="%s">%s</a></td>', $row_sv['website'], $row_sv['name'] );
```

No mess with the quotes and opening/closing tags.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following:

```
echo '<td><a href="'.$row_sv['website'].'">'.$row_sv['name'].'</a></td>';
```

Comment: Why did you change the link contents to a `name` attribute?

Comment: Do you want that as the name attribute? `echo '<td><a href="'.$row_sv['website'].'" name="'.$row_sv['name'].'">Link Text</a></td>';`

Comment: It would seem from the OP that `$row['name']` **is** the link text, not a name attribute.

Comment: I see what's happened, that was my first thought but that's since been edited. The current version of the answer is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up the quotes a bit:

```
echo '<td><a href="'.$row_sv['website'].'">'.$row_sv['name'].'</a></td>';
```

Comment: You're missing the trailing double quote `"` after `$row_sv['website']`.

Answer (score 1):

You deleted too much, and then messed up something that was ok to begin with.

Use:

```
echo '<td><a href="'.$row_sv['website'].'">'.$row_sv['name'].'</a></td>';
```

In addition to deleting too much, you also had `$row_sv['website]` instead of `$row_sv['website']` which should've cause a parse error too (unless it was just a typo here).

In the future here, you could also paste the HTML output instead of saying "it messed up my table" -- it'll make it easier for you to see the problem as well as folks here, I am sure.